# How to properly lay Tatami mats

Tags: flooring

I'm thinking of building a Japanese style room with Tatami mats in my new flat. Now I strongly suspect that this is not as easy as simply buying mats, having them delivered so I don't have to carry them 20 floors up, and placing them on the floor, but I couldn't easily find a tutorial either.

- Do I need to place something below the mats to provide air flow, or is that a bad idea?
- Are there common mistakes?
- Is there a noticeable difference between "standard" and "premium" mats?
- Is there an English language tutorial showing correct procedure that I may have overlooked.

I plan to circumfence the room with bookshelves, and the mats would ideally be flush with them.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know, but I did some brief poking around & found some items you might find useful.

I'll summarize what I gleamed to answer your questions:

- The Real (see 3rd bullet point) Tatami just goes right on the floor with nothing beneath, Tatami's are made to breathe. From an old Blog [**Wood Used Under Tatami Mat**](http://www.japan-guide.com/forum/quereadisplay.html?0%206984), scroll 2/3rd's down to 2004/8/10.
- Just not fitting them tightly & Etiquette of the room & of the Tatami. See YouTube video [**Japanese Tatami Room Etiquette**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nS7QCx-YrQA&spfreload=10)
- I didn't run across anything about Standard or Premium. But, Standard would seem to have a synthetic foam core & Real Tatami or Premium has a rice straw core. You'll have to ask the manufacturer, dealer or retailer about Standard's floor treatment or breathability.
- I didn't see any tutorial, but the video in Bullet Point 1 gets into it a little & there doesn't seem to be much of anything to it beyond throw them down & butt them tight.
- I did find something on cleaning though. See YouTube video [**Tatami Tips**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=io_-5gyg_B0).

Answer (score 0):

In my house the floorboards under the tatami's are spaced a little like decking timber with a small gap between each board, I think this maybe to allow the tatami to breath and not sweat. In winter the floor has only tatami for insulation and it is not cold.